# Ionic 4 router animation is not shown

Tags: angular6, ionic4

I created a small Ionic 4 / Angular navigation example application with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yx_xJ4m-JxE

Everything works fine except the router animation. A click on this item with `routerDirection="forward"` refreshs the whole page, instead of animating only the new page in.

```
<ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of pages">
    <ion-item [href]="p.url" [class.active-item]="selectedPath === p.url" routerDirection="forward">
        <ion-label>
            {{ p.title }}
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-menu-toggle>
```

Do I have to install a package or enable routing animations somewhre?? I'm running the project with `ionic serve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 4 navigate works like angular 6+.

```
routerLink="/notifications"
```

or in your case
    routerLink="[p.url]"

[Here you'll get more details.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)